# Existence of Nonzero Eigenvalues in a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem deals with proving that if A is a symmetric matrix and has A^3 = 0, then A must be zero. It tells me to prove this by diagonalizing the matrix.

My attempt was to prove that in the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, that for any symmetric, nonzero matrix that there must be at least one nonzero eigenvalue. This would mean that the eigenvalue diagonal matrix would be nonzero when taken to the third power. This would show that the only way to prove that A is symmetric and A^3 =0 is for it to be the zero matrix.

How would I go about generally proving that a symmetric, nonzero matrix has at least one nonzero eigenvalue?

Comment: In general a diagonalizable nilpotent matrix must be zero. Just think about the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all of the eigenvalues of $A$ were $0$, then $A$ would have to be $0$ itself. This is because the real-spectral theorem (I'm assuming $A$ was real. I felt your question assumed this.) guarantees that 
$$
A = SDS^{-1}
$$
where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and $S$ is an invertible operator. But since every eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, $D = 0$, so $A = S0 S^{-1} = 0.$

Therefore if $A$ is not $0$, it must have a nonzero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is symmetric and real, there is a $P$ such that $A=P\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)P^{-1}$. $A^3=0$ so $P\text{diag}(\lambda_1^3,\lambda_2^3,\lambda_3^3)P^{-1}=0$ so $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3$.